# W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

under what circumstances we get this error ?

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

all my code is compiling fine but i keep getting this error and notifications from my android app are not being sent into my server app i want to look into my code but im not sure what to look for when getting this error.